# Source generation in Netbeans and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, netbeans

I now use Netbeans rather than Eclipse but find that the Source code generation seems more limited than Eclipse. For example Eclipse has a function that generates delegate methods but I cannot find this in Netbeans. Is there a comparison of the functionality in the tools, and any suggestions for overcoming deficiencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delegate support has been in NetBeans for a while now (at least since 6.5).

- Click outside a method.
- Press Alt-Insert.
- Select `Delegate Method...`
- Select the field from the left panel
- Check the methods to delegate in the right panel
- Click `Generate`

As for feature comparisons... [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=feature+comparison+java+ide)